# Sql server - match any in join relation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables User and Car. User can have many cars.

I want to display all user cars if any registration match to provided argument.

```
Select u.id ,c.* From user u 
join car c on c.user = u.id
Where c.registration = 'parameter_value'
```

This simple join find for me user and specific car. But I want to return list of his every car if any car matches.Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide more information about query that is sample input and required output.

Comment: You can't do it with a single join because you must hit the [CAR] table twice, one to filter by the parameter and a second time to correlate it again with [USER]. You can use a second join to [CAR] or use a subquery like in the @GordonLinoff answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select c.*
from car c
where exists (select 1
              from car c2
              where c2.user = c.user and
                    c2.registration = @parameter
             );
```

Note that the `user` table is not needed for this query.  The only "user" column you are using is the id and that is already in `car`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WHERE clause in a subquery that will return all the users with a car that has that `'parameter_value'`:

```
select u.id, c.* 
from user u join car c on c.user = u.id
where u.id in (
  select user from car
  where registration = 'parameter_value'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try CROSS APPLY like below

```
SELECT U.ID,C.*
FROM user U
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT C.* 
    FROM Car C  
    WHERE C.user=u.Id
   and c.registration = 'parameter_value'
)C
```